Create a matrix that has a definite determinant
Consider I want to create a matrix of order $3\times 3$ that has a determinant of $25$. How can I accomplish that task? Even if I have a computer program for that, what shall be range that I need to be starting with?
What I basically need to know that, what shall be the range of the numbers within which I need to check whether the matrix having entries within this range must have that definite determinant. After a bit of study and research, I have arrived at the point that, a matrix formed of entries that represent a magic square, has the largest determinant within that range. For example, consider that I want to create a matrix using the numbers $[0-9]$ only once, then the matrix:
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
8&1&6\\3&5&7\\4&9&2
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
[a magic square it is] has the largest determinant. Why is that? Now, what shall be the matrix that has the least determinant? At least, this shall help me to have a guess of the limit of the range that I must start with to set up the desired matrix with the definite determinant?

Just a diagonal with entries 25 1 1 ?

diag 25,1,1 uses the 1 twice. [OP not clear on that requirement]

Do you require integer entries?

There are infinitely many matrices with a given determinant. What other conditions they must satisfy?

Find an arbitrary 3x3 invertible matrix $P$ first, then construct a diagonal/triangular matrix $J$ such the product of the diagonal entries of $J$ is 25. Then the determinant of the product $PJP^{-1}$ is 25. This turns your problem into solving $xyz = 25$ instead of $\det(A) = 25$ for searching such matrices.

@M.Riyan: For the matrix, $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \
d & e & f \
g & h & i \
\end{array}
\right)$$ Are these okay? $${{a\to 1,b\to 0,c\to 19,d\to -1,e\to 1,f\to 41,g\to -49,h\to -14,i\to -1746},{a\to -1,b\to 0,c\to -1,d\to 100,e\to -1,f\to 22,g\to 1,h\to 4,i\to 338}}$$ What about $${{a\to -1,b\to 3,c\to -2,d\to 1,e\to -2,f\to -2,g\to -2,h\to -1,i\to -1}}$$ What about $$\left{\left{a\to -\frac{29}{8},b\to 0,c\to -2,d\to -1,e\to -2,f\to -2,g\to 0,h\to -2,i\to 2\right}\right}$$

@Moo how are you guessing these values? Are these merely guess or there is an underlying concept behind the theory?

I am using Mathematica.

@Exodd I wish to use a number within a range only once. That's why, I have the range to pick the numbers from.

@lhf Yes, I do require integer entries

@Moo, can you a bit more explanatory about the mathematics you are talking about? You have chosen numbers to be as large as $338$ and as small as $-1746$. Why is that?

Because the algorithm has a random component to it that uses random integers.

@Gonçalo there is not any specific requirements. Except, the entries must be within the range of a integers say $0$ to $9$ and none of the numbers shall be repeated

$\det\left(\begin{matrix}8&1&6\3&5&7\4&9&2\end{matrix}\right)=-360$,$\det\left(\begin{matrix}9&5&3\4&1&8\2&7&6\end{matrix}\right)=-412$

There are exactly 1188 3$\times$3 matrices with entries in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ without repetition and determinant 25. Here is one (check with WA):
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 8 \\ 7 & 9 & 6}
$$
I wrote a program that goes through all $9!=362880$ permutations of $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ and checked the determinant of the corresponding matrix.
BTW, all numbers from $0$ to $412$ occur as determinants, except these: 324, 329, 355, 357, 358, 362, 364, 365, 367, 373, 375, 378, 381, 383, 386, 387, 394, 397, 399, 401, 403, 406, 409, 411.
See OEIS/A088214 and OEIS/A088216.

That's such a beautiful answer. Thanks.
